# Joining search results of a table that "belongs_to" another

Tags: mysql, perl, belongs-to, dbix-class

`visits` have many `visitsTasks` which belong to `tasks`.

I am looking at a particular row (`visitID`) in the `visits` table, and want to find all the tasks that were completed. Of those tasks, I want to access the `path` and `mode` columns (in `tasks` table).

```
      my $visitTasks = $visit->visits_tasks()->search(
            {'me.subsection' => 'completed'},
            {join => 'task_name' } # PROBLEM HERE
            ); 
      while(my $vt=$visitTasks->next()){
         say Dumper($vt->get_columns());

         # if completed is true then record the task
         push @{$visit{Tasks}},  {taskName => $vt->task_name, path=>$vt->path, mode=>$vt->mode } if $vt->value == 1;
      }
```

`taskName` and `value` (`visits_tasks` columns) are available. But I'm unable to find the syntax or the missing relations to get the `visitsTasks` results joined with `tasks`

---

I created a UML diagram with `dia`, transformed the graph into mySQL with `parsediasql`
, and populated the DBIX::class with `dbicdump`.

[image: UML diagram]

## visitsTasks

```
package lncddb3::Schema::Result::VisitsTask;
#...
=head2 task_name

Type: belongs_to

Related object: L<lncddb3::Schema::Result::Task>

=cut

__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
  "task_name",
  "lncddb3::Schema::Result::Task",
  { taskName => "taskName" },
  {
    is_deferrable => 1,
    join_type     => "LEFT",
    on_delete     => "RESTRICT",
    on_update     => "RESTRICT",
  },  
);
```

## Tasks

```
package lncddb3::Schema::Result::Task;
# ...
=head2 visits_tasks

Type: has_many

Related object: L<lncddb3::Schema::Result::VisitsTask>

=cut

__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "visits_tasks",
  "lncddb3::Schema::Result::VisitsTask",
  { "foreign.taskName" => "self.taskName" },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);
```

## schema

```
create table visits (
   visitID      int unsigned    not null auto_increment          ,
   peopleID     int unsigned                      ,
   visitdate    date                              ,
   visitTime    time                              ,
   scanID       varchar(50)                       ,
   noShow       bool                              ,
   schedualedBy varchar(50)                       ,
   checkedInBy  varchar(50)                       ,
   googleid     varchar(50)                       ,
   age          double unsigned                   ,
   onMeds       varchar(20)                       ,
   location     varchar(50)                       ,
   cohort       varchar(50)      default "control",
   quality      int                               ,
   constraint pk_visits primary key (visitID)
) 
create table visitsTasks (
   peopleID   int unsigned ,
   visitID    int unsigned ,
   taskName   varchar(50)  ,
   subsection varchar(50)  ,
   value      varchar(50)
) 
create table tasks (
   taskName varchar(50)  not null,
   taskDesc char(200)            ,
   path     varchar(300)         ,
   mode     varchar(50)          ,--  fMRI, PET, MEG,fMRI+eyetracking,eyetracking, etc
   constraint pk_tasks primary key (taskName)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to spend more time with the [Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Multi-step_prefetch). The joined columns are not at the same level as the original columns.

```
$vt->task_name->path #not $vt->path
```